# Javascript - "history.pushState" replaces regular "&" with "&amp;". How to avoid it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pushstate

I am doing an AJAX request in Rails and after executing it, I'd like to modify the URL and put there all there parameters.

So this is how I obtained the relative URL in the Rails controller:

```
@url_params = request.original_fullpath 
# => /members/info/detail?currency=usd&year=2016
```

Then, in the JS file:

```
console.log("<%= @url_params %>");
# => /members/info/detail?currency=usd&amp;year=2016
```

So I tried:

```
var url = "<%= @url_params %>";
var replaced_url = url.replace("&amp;", "&");
# => /members/info/detail?currency=usd&amp;year=2016
```

but it doesn't work neither.

When I do `history.pushState("", "", replaced_url);`, in the URL is still the `$amp;` instead of only `&`.

How to push the URL without the `&amp;` characters?

Thank you

Comment: that's not JS converting your entities...

Comment: `&amp;` just a html symbol that represents `&`

Comment: Yeah, it is, and it's working with that, but I am just trying to get right of that and display the URL in the "classic" `&` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe by default rails html encodes your output to get the unencoded output try

```
var url = "<%=raw @url_params %>";
```

Comment: This is probably safe, but it's arguably safer to do `var url = <%= raw @url_params.to_json %>;`.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var replaced_url = url.replace("&amp;", "&");
```

to

```
var replaced_url = url.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
```

it seems like, url has multiple &'s, because of which single replacement of string would not work, so consider group replace for such things.

know more about : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: Thanks @ameenulla0007, I found that article and tried that approach, but didn't make it work neither way. To the URL are still pushed `&amp;`.

Comment: would you please, try posting a fiddle, with one example url, what you are trying to replace, so that i can consider working with it.. meanwhile check my tried fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3w5zhufn/